# Is there a difference between "cured" and "recovered"?

Tags: word-choice

In reference to [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23619/is-there-a-cure-for-ebola) I asked there, a user said that the phrase 'recovered' and 'cured' generally mean the same thing.

Is this true?   I was under the impression 'cured' meant a final resolution, while 'recovered' only meant a temporary resolution.

So when news articles tell me a patient of Ebola was cured, am I to understand that have literally been cured? Or is cured just a synonym of recovered?

Comment: "Cured of" and "recovered from" are chalk and cheese. Why do you ask? :)

Comment: Or is that a "thinly veiled question?"  :)

Comment: You can be "sufficiently recovered for work". You cannot be "sufficiently cured", since it is a binary thing - you're either cured (hale) or not (sick). (Unless you're a piece of jerky, in which case you can be sufficiently cured to eat, I suppose)

Comment: I puzzle to understand why the question has been down voted!

Comment: Have you looked up the words in a dictionary?  Checked any usage examples in standard writing?

Comment: A dead person is cured of insomnia. A sleeping person is recovering from insomnia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Recover' is a word that applies generally, and can refer to all kinds of things, not only illnesses and injuries. You can, for example, ask 'has he recovered from the shock of his exam results yet?'; or 'has she recovered from winning the lottery?'.

'Cure', in this sense, applies mostly to diseases and illnesses, rarely to injuries. So one is 'cured' of scarlet fever, but one recovers from breaking one's leg.

As you have also rightly deduced 'cure' does imply a complete recovery.

'Cure' also suggests to me that there was some kind of medical intervention - drug, or treatment, which led to it. However one can 'recover' without the aid of a doctor or nurse.